# Getting my values from an if statement to show outside of the if statement in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to create a command that lets me write to a json file. I'm able to do that but I'm struggling to get some values out of my if statement.

Here is my code

```
foreach($update as $key => $value)
{
  $name = '';
  $hours = '';

  if($value != 0)
  {
      $name = $key;
      $hours = $value;
  }

  $array = [
    $name => $hours
  ]
}
```

but when I run my code I get a blank $name and a blank $hours

Comment: Since its in loop,you need to add $name $hours in array like  `$array[$name] = $hours` at the end of loop and declare `$array  = array();` just above foreach loop and also check if $update has value other then 0 or not using `dd($update)`

Answer (score 1):

You're always getting last record. Also, you can ignore redundant values in your data.

I guess these lines can help you

```
    foreach($update as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value == 0)  {
            continue;
        }

        $name = $key;
        $hours = $value;

        $array[$name] = $hours;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe these lines help you

```
    $update = [1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c'];
    foreach ($update as $key => $value) {
        if ($value !== 0) {
            $name = $key;
            $hours = $value;
            $array[$name] = $hours; // $array[]= [$name=>$hours];
        }
    }
```

*note* : if $update array values contain strings will return true at all because at php
('a' == 0) will return true for that i used !==